# pass argument to groupby and agg in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use agg after groupby and pass in two parameters, param1 and param2. I tried the following but failed. What is the correct way to do that? Thanks.

```
def myfun(x, param1, param2):
    #some calculations
    return result

B = A.groupby([A.index, 'time']).agg({'salary': myfun, param1, param2})
```

Comment: If you are OK with lambdas, `.agg({'salary': lambda x: myfun(x, param1, param2)})` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
param1=1
param2=100
A.groupby([A.index,'time'])['salary'].agg(myfun, param1, param2)
```

or as @ayhan suggests:

```
A.groupby([A.index,'time']).agg({'salary':lambda x: myfunc(x, param1, param2)})
```

Comment: With renaming being phased out, this solution is not ideal
lambda gets named as <lambda> and more than 1 of these will result in a frame with 2 columns of the same name.
How do you propose to get around this?

Comment: I want to use something like:
`def string_search(x, field, st):`  
`return x[field].str.contains(st).sum()`  
`text1 = 'TRF' `  
`text2 = 'UTC'`  
`field1 = 'ail_front'`  
`field2 = 'ail_back'`  
`df.groupby('filename').agg({field1: [string_search, field1, text1, string_search, field1, text2],`  
`field2: [string_search, field2, text1, string_search, field2, text2]})`  

but this does not work as suggested